# How do I make all objects visible at any zoom level/distance from the camera?

Tags: three.js

I have a scene with hundreds of objects, however not all of them are visible unless I move the camera towards them.

Here's part of the scene from above - note how the yellow wireframes seem to cut off halfway:

[image]

The more I zoom in, the more becomes visible:

[image]

I would like for all objects to be visible at all times, not just when the camera is near them.

Is there a setting/property for this or is it not that simple?

I am using a `PerspectiveCamera` with the following settings (code abridged for brevity):

```js
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, 1280 / 720);

camera.far = Infinity;
camera.position.x = 0;
camera.position.y = 1024;
camera.position.z = 1024;

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(camera);
```

Comment: Looks like you need to adjust camera frustum's `far` plane.

Comment: @prisoner849 my fault for not including my code, apologies - it's already set to `Infinity`.

Comment: Wow, so after wasting a ton of time it seems that setting the `far` property to a large number (`0x10000` in my use-case) is what fixed it. The documentation for `PerspectiveCamera` mentions the word "infinity" so I assumed it was a valid value... it's not. Post your comment as an answer if you'd like, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user @prisoner849's comment, I realised that `Infinity` is not a valid `far` value for a `PerspectiveCamera`.

Fixed code:

```js
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, 1280 / 720, 0.1, 0x10000);
```